# Error: Cannot find module './src/commandstools/ping.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Code: Just a command handler. Here is the code to my command handler:

```js
const { REST } = require(`@discordjs/rest`);
const { Routes } = require(`discord-api-types/v9`);
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleCommands = async () => {
        const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/commands`);
        for (const folder of commandFolders) {
            const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./src/commands/${folder}`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

            const { commands, commandArray } = client;
            for (const file of commandFiles) {
                const command = require(`../../src/Commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
                console.log("Command: $(command.data.name) has passed through the handler");
            }
        }

        const clientId = "1020364253842116720";
        const rest = new REST({ version: `9` }).setToken(process.env.token);
        try {
            console.log("Started refreshing application (/) commands.");

            await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(clientId), {
                body: client.commanndArray,
            });

            console.log("Successfully reload application (/) commands.");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
        // change this marc if you add it to more servers
    };
};
```

Error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../src/Commands/tools/ping.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\gacoo\Desktop\Radon\src\functions\handlers\handleCommands.js
- C:\Users\gacoo\Desktop\Radon\src\bot.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at client.handleCommands (C:\Users\gacoo\Desktop\Radon\src\functions\handlers\handleCommands.js:15:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gacoo\Desktop\Radon\src\bot.js:23:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\gacoo\\Desktop\\Radon\\src\\functions\\handlers\\handleCommands.js',
    'C:\\Users\\gacoo\\Desktop\\Radon\\src\\bot.js'
  ]
}
```

I am running Node.js v18.14.1.

I cannot see the problem with it at all, please help it is for a multipurpose discord bot.

Answer (score 0):

If `s.readdirSync('./src/commands')` is successful, you don't need to go back two directories to get to `src`:

```js
const command = require(`./src/Commands/${folder}/${file}`);
```